# MVC 4.0 - Xml to model

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a system that returns xml, and I need to build some MVC pages that use this data. I'm using MVC 4.0 and C# FW4.0.
I'm populating my models like this:

```
List<PersonName> tmpList = new List<PersonName>();
IEnumerable<PersonName> PeopleNames = tmpList;                
XDocument oDoc = XDocument.Parse(sResponse);

var vPeopleNames = from c in oDoc.Descendants("PersonName")
                   select new PersonName()
                   {
                       PersonID = (string)c.Element("PersonID"),                                 
                       FirstName = (string)c.Element("FirstName"),
                       LastName = (string)c.Element("LastName")
                   };

PeopleNames = vPeopleNames;
var oModel = PeopleNames;           

return View("PeopleNamesList", PeopleNames);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this automatically. I don't want to specify the names of the fields "PersonID", "FirstName" and "LastName". If i'll have 50 fields it will be too painful...

Comment: I am actually running into a similar scenario. I could not think of anything else than writing some reflection code that will map the XElement to a model.

Comment: If you have classes you can serialize the classes which produces XML.  You can also write a DATASET/DATTATABLE to xml format.

Comment: @jdweng: If he has an xsd/schema file, you meant, no ?

Comment: I'd be looking at [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) - this will map XML to an object.  If you want specifics, you should add the class definitions and some XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize from and to an `XElement` using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) with the aid of [`XNode.CreateReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XContainer.CreateWriter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.createwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The following extension methods do the job:

```
public static class XObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XContainer element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            object result = (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces NoStandardXmlNamespaces()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes.
        return ns;
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, NoStandardXmlNamespaces()); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes by default.
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(null, ns);
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        return obj.SerializeToXElement(serializer, (omitStandardNamespaces ? NoStandardXmlNamespaces() : null));
    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXElement<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }
}
```

Then use them like:

```
        var vPeopleNames = (from c in oDoc.Descendants("PersonName")
                            select c.Deserialize<PersonName>()).ToList();

        var peopleXml = vPeopleNames.SerializeToXElement(); // Creates a root element named <ArrayOfPersonName> containing all people names as child elements.
```

With the `PersonName` class defined as follows:

```
public class PersonName
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```